# Personalised name in constructor for different subclasses

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, compiler-errors

Instead of "Car" is there a way to set the name variable of each object according to its class, for example "Turbo 01" or "Tank 02" or "Buggy 03", where id contains the amount of vehicles created.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
static int id = 0; //Total Number of cars right now
class Car
{

private:
        std::string name;
Car()
    {
      std::ostringstream tmp;
      std::string temp;
      tmp << "Car" << ++id;
      temp = tmp.str();
    }
Car(std::string name){this->name=name; id++;}

};

class Turbo : public Car()
{

Turbo():Car()
    {

    }
Turbo(std::string name):Car(name);
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: In C++ constructors are special member functions, do not have names, and cannot be explicitly called.

Comment: `std::array type;` Does this actually compile?

Comment: when you call the base constructor, add it with a : e.g. Turbo(std::string name) : Car(name, "Turbo") {..} but the std::array is not correct, array is a template and needs to be instantiated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's make sure that the `class Car` compiles by providing the two required template arguments [`std::array`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/) :  type and size.  For example: `std::array<int, 10>`.

The problem is that `Turbo` needs a valid constructor for its base type `Car` before it can do anythin else. There are two ways, for it to work:

- Either you design Car so that there is a default consructor (i.e.without parameters)
- Or you put the constructor for Car in the initialisezer list of the Turbo.

For your edited question, the problem is that the `Car` constructor must be visible for the derived class, so either `public` or `protected`, but not `private`. You can also use default parameters to get rid of redundant code.

Here a solution:

```
class Car
{
private:
    static int id;     //Total Number of cars right now  SO MEK IT a static class member
    std::string name;

public:     // public or protected so that derived classes can access it
    Car(std::string n="Car")  // if a name is provided, it will be used, otherwhise it's "Car".
    {
        std::ostringstream tmp;
        std::string temp;
        tmp << n << ++id;
        name = tmp.str();  // !! corrected
    }
};
int Car::id = 0;   // initialisation of static class member

class Turbo : public Car
{
public:                                    // !! corrected
    Turbo(std::string n="Turbo") :Car(n)   // !!
    {   } 
};
```

Comment: Could you please update your answer? I made some changes to address that issue, around the same time you answered.

Comment: Yes, I see that you've change.  I'll working on it ;-)